# Combine Two Python Dictionary to One JSON (Two Objects)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Example I have the following two python dictionary :

```
a = [{'make': 'Ferrari', 'model': 458, 'price': 9999}, {'make': 'BMW', 'model': 'F10', 'price': 8888}, {'make': 'Porsche', 'model': 'GT3', 'price': 7777}]

b = [{'make': 'Kawasaki', 'model': 'ZX10R', 'price': 6666}, {'make': 'Honda', 'model': 'CBR1000RR', 'price': 5555}, {'make': 'BMW', 'model': 'S1000RR', 'price': 4444}]
```

I want the JSON to look like this where it consists of two objects, "car" and "bike" :

```
{
  "car":
   [  
       {  
          "make":"Ferrari",
          "model":"458",
          "price":"9999"
       },
       {  
          "make":"BMW",
          "model":"F10",
          "price":"8888"
       },
       {  
          "make":"Porsche",
          "model":"GT3",
          "price":"7777"
       }
   ]
   "bike":
   [  
       {  
          "make":"Kawasaki",
          "model":"ZX10R",
          "price":"6666"
       },
       {  
          "make":"Honda",
          "model":"CBR1000RR",
          "price":"5555"
       },
       {  
          "make":"BMW",
          "model":"S1000RR",
          "price":"4444"
       }
   ]
}
```

Any ideas how to do so? Cant seem to figure it out. Thanks :)

Comment: `{'car':a, 'bike':b}`?

Comment: If collection `a` and collection `b` are always going to be collections of cars and bikes respectively, then the above solution is all you need.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, just tried it and it works. Didn't know its that easy. Thanks :)

Comment: @idjaw, thanks I managed to solve it :)